# How to embed vispy canvas in PyQt5 frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, vispy

Hey I want to embed the output window of vispy canvas in my pyqt5 generated Gui. I don't know much about vispy so please help thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with Gui generated ?, ie you have generated it with Qt Designer and pyuic.

Comment: I have created a Pyqt5 gui with self written python script and now i want to open a vispy window in one of the frame of the gui.

Comment: yeah i will but can you tell me how to embed this canvas in a frame

Comment: why -1 at this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as vispy is using Qt as backend, you must use `.native`, this parameter will make the canvas use QGLWidget, for example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import vispy.app
import sys

canvas = vispy.app.Canvas()
w = QMainWindow()
widget = QWidget()
w.setCentralWidget(widget)
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
widget.layout().addWidget(canvas.native)
widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton())
w.show()
vispy.app.run()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153449/discussion-on-answer-by-eyllanesc-how-to-embed-vispy-canvas-in-pyqt5-frame). Please remember to update the answer with all relevant information!